# Getting dates type varchar to display in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I am trying to add a date into my database. When I had it the type set to date it would be set to 00000000 when trying to add data to db, so I changed it to varchar, but now when I input dates it says for example -1995 or -2000. I just want to include the date the user selects into the database. I am so stuck and have tried absolutely everything I can think of.

If anyone has any ideas as how to fix this, I would be very grateful. Thanks, below is the code I have

HTML

```
 <span class="dpWrapper"><p class="date"> Date From: </p>
<input type="text" class="datepickerdoc dpInputFrom"> </span>
<span class="dpWrapper"><p class="date">Date To: </p> 
<input type="text" class="datepickerdoc dpInputTo"> </span>
```

jAVASCRIPT

```
$(function () {
     $(".datepickerdoc").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
});

hotelImg.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var data = {
        fromDate : document.getElementsByClassName('dpInputFrom')[0].value,
        toDate : document.getElementsByClassName('dpInputTo')[0].value,
        id : hotelData.hotel_id
    };

    $.ajax({
    url: 'php/uploadItinerary.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: console.log,
    error: console.log
    });
    });
```

PHP

```
$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
$hotelId = $_POST['id'];
$dateTo = $_POST['toDate'];
$dateFrom = $_POST['fromDate'];
```

The hotel id successfully is added to the database, just not the dates.

Comment: Just a suggestion, when you want to select a single element, instead of using one of the methods that returns a collection and then selecting the first element in the collection, you can just use `.querySelector`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance i am not sure what you mean but i dont really want to change my code other than the date stuff as it works

Comment: Where's the php code supposed to store the date into DB? Do you make any format conversion? JS-side, your dateformat 'dd-mm-yy' is not the default mysql dateformat ('yyyy-mm-dd').

Comment: I mean instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('dpInputFrom')[0].value` you can do `document.querySelector('.dpInputFrom').value`. Needlessly verbose code is generally more difficult to read and debug.

Comment: @fpierrat into the date-from and date-to columns. Both of these are varchars, i couldnt get it working using dates

Comment: I got the values of dates with code provided whats the server side code?

Comment: @fpierrat Updated question and added php

Comment: @JoeWarner just added it there, there is just a query below this inserting the values into the database

Comment: Have you tested php-side what you get in $_POST['toDate'] and $_POST['fromDate']? Are these the awaited values? What's your DB request? Nobody can help you if you don't help us helping you...

Comment: @fpierrat i tried to use the console log to try and get the vales of the dates but it wasnt working, no errors or anything, there was just nothing appearing in the console. I dont know what awaited values means, db request is INSERT INTO zz_upload_itinerary (`user_id`, `hotel_id`, `date_to`, `date_from`) VALUES ($userId, $hotelId, $dateTo, $dateFrom)

Comment: just temporarily add this line at the beginning of your php code:  `die("dateTo: ". $_POST['toDate']." - dateFrom: ".$_POST['fromDate']);` to send back to the browser the values that were sent to your php script, so you can see them in your console or network monitor.

Comment: @fpierrat I did this and it is getting the correct dates, dateTo: 30-03-2018 - dateFrom: 14-03-2018 success  this is what I was getting in my console. (yes I know I need validation so they cannot select a date that has passed)